# How do I set up SSH into my Mac with Lion?

Tags: ssh, osx-lion

I recently bought a Macbook Air with Lion. I would like to ssh into my Mac at work. How do I set this up?

I have a private and public key, so I will likely use that option to allow access into my mac.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This should give you the guidance you need:
http://www.stocksy.co.uk/articles/Mac/ssh_on_mac_os_x/

Comment: Thanks, I have tried altering Apple -> System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login and then sshing into my mac air with `ssh davidfaux@dhcp-12-259-119-81.yale.edu` as the instructions told me. However, this method fails since the terminal notes that the host dhcp-12-259-119-81.yale.edu is not recognized.

Comment: By the way, this IP address is fake, so I didn't reveal anything :)

Comment: You seem to be behind a firewall that's blocking SSH access from outside. Could that be? From where are you trying to SSH in, actually? You can also try to find out your real computer's IP (not the `dhcp-..` hostname) and ssh to that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple -> System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login.

Comment: It shows the IP of the local network, how can I ssh from the outside?

Comment: You can't, @ilyo.  Private addresses are only locally accessible.

Comment: I know I can't use that address outside, I'm asking how *can* I ssh to the mac from the outside.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to SSH from work to home, you'll need to do the following:

- Get the **external IP** address of your home network. You can obtain this by going to [this website](http://www.whatismyip.com). If you ISP changes your IP frequently, you'll have to use something like [Dyn DNS](http://dyn.com/dns/).
- Open **port 22** on your firewall/router and point it to the local IP address of the Mac you want to connect to. Instructions for this step vary on your firewall/router model. You may want to set up a **DHCP reservation** for this Mac so the internal IP address doesn't change.
- On the Mac your want to connect *to*, open **System Preferences → Sharing** and enable **Remote Login**.
- You should now be able to run the command `ssh user@ip.of.your.mac`, replacing "user" with the home computer's username and the "ip.of.your.mac" with the home IP address.

Answer (score 2):

1. Simply activate the option in Preferences : "Remote login".
2. Access your mac :

   `ssh username@ip.of.your.mac`